# Where can I find head MRI files?

Tags: research, mri

I have to calculate some anatomic values on different brains so I have to work on different MRI images for my project. Where can I find MRI images for this?

Answer (score 2):

Brain Imaging Data Structure (BIDS) is a simple and intuitive way to organize and describe neuroimaging and behavioral data. You can find it on [bids.neuroimaging.io](https://bids.neuroimaging.io/).

> BIDS is heavily inspired by the format used internally by the OpenfMRI repository (now known as OpenNeuro.org). While working on BIDS we consulted many neuroscientists to make sure it covers most common experiments, but at the same time is intuitive and easy to adopt. The specification is intentionally based on simple file formats and folder structures to reflect current lab practices and make it accessible to a wide range of scientists coming from different backgrounds.

Full public datasets including MRI data (for data analysis) can be found on [openneuro.org](https://openneuro.org/public/datasets). Other BIDS example data can be found in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/bids-standard/bids-examples).